# INSERT INTO SELECT: скопировать строки, сохранив порядок

Tags: mysql, sql

Пытаюсь скопировать "подобъекты", принадлежащие object_id=123, меняя при object_id на 234.

```
INSERT INTO sub_objects(object_id, field1) 
(SELECT 234, field1 FROM sub_objects WHERE object_id=123 ORDER BY id ASC)
```

Работает, но при этом порядок вставляемых строк(по возрастанию id) не совпадает с оригинальным - `SELECT 234, field1 FROM sub_objects WHERE object_id=123 ORDER BY id ASC`, не смотря на явную сортировку.

Как уточнить запрос, чтобы порядок вставляемых строк соблюдался?

Comment: Структура таблицы, упрощённо: id, object_id, field1?

Comment: @Bakhuss, ну да

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Понятие порядка строк в MySQL (как и в любой другой DBMS) - НЕ СУЩЕСТВУЕТ. Таблица - это куча. Несортированная.

Бесполезно говорить, что существует некий порядок физического расположения записей на накопителе (особенно если существует кластерный индекс). Всё равно это физическое расположение не обязано отображаться (хотя и может) на порядок возвращения записей по запросу.

Если нужен некий порядок - необходимо в запросе, получающем данные из таблиц(ы), явно указать требуемый порядок сортировки. Только в этом случае появится понятие порядка - и то только для тех записей, у которых значение выражения сортировки различается.

Если у нескольких записей значение выражения сортировки совпадает, то порядок записей внутри этой группы также не определён (не существует). И два последовательных запроса имеют полное право вернуть записи этой группы в различном порядке, сохраняя лишь положение этой группы внутри всего набора записей.

Comment: Мб я неправильно сформулировал вопрос, но порядок тут определяется полем id. Я хочу скопировать записи в таблице таким образом, чтобы id вставляемых записей увеличивался в том же порядке что и у копируемых записей. Т.е. чтобы записи вставились в том же порядке, что и были возвращены при select-е. Задача элементарная, вот только как это сделать в одном запросе...

Comment: *Я хочу скопировать записи в таблице таким образом, чтобы id вставляемых записей увеличивался в том же порядке что и у копируемых записей.* Навскидку вижу 2 варианта. Первый - копирование по одной записи. Второй - экспорт записей в файл (.sql либо .csv) и последующий импорт. Ну и третий вариант - после копирования в любом порядке выполнить переприсвоение (UPDATE) id у новых записей в соответствии с порядком при сортировке по id старых записей.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, не думал что нужны такие костыли для простой задачи)

Comment: @rewardealer Задача не "простая", а "странная". ID ведь синтетический автоинкрементный ключ. Его дело - уникальность блюсти да связи и контроль целостности обеспечивать. А какой-то там порядок записей - этим должно заниматься другое поле. Специально для этого в структуре создаваемое.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте курсор, и вставляйте записи в цикле обхода курсора.